# onDataChange stuck in infinite loop

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a rating system for restaurants and bars using Firebase. So far I am able to read and write individual ratings. The problem I am having is that in order to calculate the average rating for a particular restaurant I need to get the amount of ratings stored and total value of all ratings stored. At the moment I am struggling to store the amount of ratings. Here is my code

```
Query RetrieveRating =  databaseReference.child("ratings").child("porterhouse");
RetrieveRating.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot postSnapshot) {

   //get data from snapshot
    String  data = postSnapshot.child("numRating").getValue().toString();

    if (!data.equals(null)) {
        String numRating = (String) postSnapshot.child("numRating").getValue();

        count = Integer.valueOf(numRating);
        count++;

        ratingCounter = Integer.toString(count);

        databaseReference.child("ratings").child("porterhouse").child("numRating").setValue(ratingCounter);
     }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

What is happening is it is taking the current stored value, adding 1 to it and writing it back to the database, however as each time it is stored the onDataChange() method is called, adding plus 1 again and again making an infinite loop. 
My question is, is there any changes I can make in order to prevent this, or even a different way to configure this?
Thanks

UPDATE

json code is as follows:

```
    {
      "ratings" : {
        "porterhouse" : {
          "numRating" : "0",
          "totalRating" : "0"
        }
  }
```

Comment: Post your json structure

Comment: @MartinDeSimone updated to show relavent part of json code

Comment: That would really make a loop based on your code because the ChildEventListener would listen to all changes on that specific path and changing that path inside the listener would trigger it again and again

Comment: Could you post your whole JSON Database Schema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use addListenerForSingleValueEvent

```
RetrieveRating.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot postSnapshot) {

            //get data from snapshot
            String  data = postSnapshot.child("numRating").getValue().toString();

            if (!data.equals(null)) {
                String numRating = (String) postSnapshot.child("numRating").getValue();

                count = Integer.valueOf(numRating);
                count++;

                ratingCounter = Integer.toString(count);



                databaseReference.child("ratings").child("porterhouse").child("numRating").setValue(ratingCounter);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Also you should use firebase transactions for incrementing counters

Comment: Thank you Martin, working perfectly. Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

While Martin's answer solves the infinite loop, it leaves a problem in your approach. If two users rate the restaurant at almost the same time, their changes may interfere with each other.

To solve this problem, as Martin says, you should [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions):

```
DatabaseReference ratingRef =  databaseReference.child("ratings/porterhouse/numRating");
postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        int count;
        try {
            count = Integer.parseInt(mutableData.getValue(String.class));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
        mutableData.setValue(Integer.toString(count));
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "countTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```

I'm not really sure why you're storing the counter as a string. I'd highly recommend storing it as a number, in which case this code becomes a lot simpler:

```
DatabaseReference ratingRef =  databaseReference.child("ratings/porterhouse/numRating");
postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        Integer count = Integer.parseInt(mutableData.getValue(Integer.class));
        if (count == null) count = 0;
        count++;
        mutableData.setValue(count);
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "countTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still struggling with it even after adding the addListenerForSingleValueEvent() and you have a hash need to increment value inside the dataChange() which is bad practice as cleared above you simply can add a boolean object initially false and test inside the dataChange() method if it still false => setvalue and set the boolean to true ,it translate for the case above as :

```
boolean is_added = false;

onDataChange(){
//after increment and befor setValue()
if(!is_added){
//setValue() set what ever you want on that reference 
is_added = true ;
}
}
```